# Apply CSS style to flash message

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra, erb

My app is based on Sinatra.  I am using the sinatra-flash gem to generate flash messages if the user does not select enough items to compare.  This aspect of things works, but I cannot seem to apply the style I want to the messages.  Here is my css:

```
.warning {
      background-color: #f89406;
      border-color: #e96506;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
```

and the code from the view:

```
<% if flash[:warning] %>
  <div class="warning"><%= flash[:warning] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: do you have correct linking to css file ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure what the issue was, but restarting the server several times eventually got it to start working.

Comment: Odds are good that restarting the server didn't fix it. The browser flushing its cache and reloading the page probably helped, or a cache between the server and the browser finally updated. Making sure you run Sinatra in development mode while developing will help.

Answer (score -1):

Restarted server for fifth time and it started working. *shrug*